# match substring with a string

Tags: javascript

I am facing a problem in matching a substring with a String. My substring and string are something like

```
var str="My name is foo.I have bag(s)"
 var substr="I have bag(s)"
```

now when I use **str.match(substr)** it returns null probably because match() function takes input as a regex and in my case it gets confused with the '('. I tried using '\'before round brackets but it didn't worked. **indexOf()** function is working but I am not allowed to use that. I also used test() and exec() but without any success

Comment: If you only want to check if a string contains a substring, do `!!~str.indexOf(substr)`, or even better in ES6, `str.contains(substr)`.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Can you show us your output that you are looking for

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I guess javascript doen't have any contains method.

Comment: @Mayank If you are not allowed to use `.indexOf` (ie in a homework assignment) you can always check it character by character.

Comment: @bipen In my code.a message containing '(' character is returned from action file to a jsp file and in jsp that message is to be compared with a hardcore message containing '(' in properties file. When compared and true is returned I need to show a error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In modern engines you can just use [String.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

```
str.includes( substr )
```

If you want something that works in older browsers and avoids [String.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), you could implement `includes`, by manually loop through the string:

```
String.prototype.includes = function ( substr, start ) {
    var i = typeof start === 'number' ? start : 0;
    // Condition exists early if there are not enough characters
    // left in substr for j to ever reach substr.length
    for ( var j = 0; i + substr.length < this.length + j + 1; ++i ) {
        j = substr[j] === this[i] ? j + 1 : 0;
        if ( j === substr.length )
            return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

If you are insistent on using a regex test you can use the escape function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/772035), to properly espace the substr to be used in a regex; in this case it adds a backslash before the `(` and `)`:

```
new RegExp( substr.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') ).test( str )
```